# ACF Post Object in Timber not showing on page template

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields, timber

Data isn't showing on page template using ACF Post Object and calling it with Timber.

Tried to add the data to index.php and the news.php template.

ACF Post Object Field Name:

```
news_author_data
```

news.php

```
$post = new TimberPost();
$context['post'] = $post;

$context['news_author'] = new 
TimberPost(get_field('news_author_data'));
Timber::render('core/news.twig', $context);
```

news.twig

```
{% for news in news_author %}
  test
{% endfor %}
```

No error message.  Just no data.

Answer (score 1):

You're going about it the wrong way, support for ACF is baked into Timber, as per the docs here:

[https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/acf-cookbook/]

Assuming this is a repeater field all you need to do is add this to your news.twig file

```
<div class="my-list">
    {% for item in post.meta('news_author_data') %}
        <div class="item">
            <h4>{{ item.my_repeater_field }}</h4>
            <h6>{{ item.my_repeater_field }}</h6>
            <img src="{{ Image(item.picture).src }}" />
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If `get_field('news_author_data')` returns an array of post objects you can't put the collection directly into the "new TimberPost" constructor. You have to loop through them like so:

```php
$post = new TimberPost();
$context['post'] = $post;

$context['news_author'] = array_map(function($post) {
    return new TimberPost($post);
}, get_field('news_author_data'));

Timber::render('core/news.twig', $context);
```

Hope this helps.